# 'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've tried to run 'yarn server' and 'yarn dev' but it always comes up with this error ***'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*** I've also tried to run 'yarn info', 'yarn upgrade' and 'yarn add yarn' but it still didn't work.

Comment: Are using window or unix operating system?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: hope my answer helps.

Comment: ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000      
error Command failed with exit code 4294967295. This happened but I don't know what to do next :/

Comment: try to run via yarn dev

Comment: yarn run v1.22.5
$ next dev
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\henke\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)    
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
error Command failed with exit code 1. This error showed up

Comment: go to `next.config.js` file and remove all the code in that file. It should work now.

Comment: yarn run v1.22.5
$ next dev
'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1. Still with the same problem

Answer (score 3):

delete node module and package-lock.json. (note: not package.json delete package-lock.json)
then reinstall all dependencies with npm i.

Answer (score 2):

next is not recognized as a yarn command. Please install next globally by this command:

```
yarn global add next
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your node module, so try to check if the node module is installed properly or not.
To install the node module try: npm i or npm install

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps

`npm install`

`npm install react react-dom next`

`npm run dev`